# Python with SimPy on Eclipse installation error (Windows 7)

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, simpy

I have been using the PyDev in eclipse for quite a while with no problem. Today I installed SimPy in my Python and  I think it is installed ok, meaning that in idle commands like:

```
>>> from SimPy.Simulation import *     
>>> now()
```

works fine.

Then I tried to configure the PyDev again so that I can use SimPy with eclipse. In eclipse I chose Windows->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter – Python. Then new, gave the name Python 2.7 and added the C:\Python27\python.exe as Interpreter executable. This is what I have done in the past and worked fine.

But now I get an error message “Error getting info on the interpreter”. From ErrorLog I get:No output was in the standard output when trying to create the interpreter info.
The error output contains: `ImportError: No module named site`

In my home variables I have:

`PYTHONHOME -> C:\Python27`

`PYTHONPATH -> C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\SimPy`

can anyone tell me what is wrong? My system is Windows 7. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after hours. It seems that in the \eclipse\plugins there were some com.python.pydev. folders left. Removed them gone through the whole process again. It seems to work now.